# why we use chaining in jQuery instead of varaible reference?

Tags: jquery, chaining

i just want know what is the methodology behind chaining system in jQuery ?
why we use chaining system instead of JavaScript variable ref.
for example **way 1** :

```
$('myDiv').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
```

I can also like this also without chaining **way 2**:

```
var a = $('myDiv');
a.removeClass('off');
a.addClass('on');
```

What is the difference between way1 and way2? I have tried both and both are working.

Comment: The difference is extra unnecessary global variable `a`.

Comment: Visual only. A matter a preference.

Comment: @Lekhnath Only global in this example, *of course*.

Comment: my code was just an example for understanding chaining use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All jQuery manipulations return a reference to the modified object. Hence, chaining is simply reusing the results of previous command. Using chaining, you can write effective "one-liners", but for longer algorithms I prefer variable references.

Answer (score 1):

Many *non-value* jQuery function return a reference to the jQuery object. Obviously `filter`s and `find`s etc change the set returned.

The difference is an extra *local* variable and slightly *shorter code*. Use with caution as not all jQuery methods return the same set.